# Android lollipop not displaying the keyboard input

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I am totally new to android. I have created one simple sign up and login page using visual studio. this app is running on all the android version except android lollipop. In android lollipop, app is opening the login page and we navigated to signup page. Here some of the xamarin.entry fields will be there to get input from user. User able to click the entry box and keyboard also appearing, but entered letters not displaying anything in the entry box. But input is reading from the keyboard. When we navigating to login page, that time entered values are displaying in the entry box.
We are using xamarin.forms and Entry box to get the input.

Please guide me to resolve this strange issue?

Comment: I have searched the java implementation of akka...ask() but i couldn't find? Please redirect me also to the java code of ask.

Comment: I have posted an answer fill free to ask any question

Answer (score 5):

You can send async request in akka like this

```
           final Timeout timeout = new Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           final Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(actor, msg, timeout);
           final String result = (String) Await.result(future, timeout.duration());
```

And inside actor in onReceive method you can return output like this

```
        getSender().tell(result, getSender());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Amit.. I understood clearly what u told and found the exact place of sending and receiving akka request. Now I have one doubt.. In ODL, There are many request will be raised against the actor.. So i want to track  both the sending end and receiving end correctly.. that is which receiving logs for which sending logs... Is ther any way to track the akka request from the both end???

Answer (score 0):

This articles contains nice described examples http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html#Use_with_Actors
http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-akka-actors-ask-examples-future-await-timeout-result

End example from Akka vendor:

https://github.com/write2munish/Akka-Essentials/blob/master/ActorMessagingExample/src/main/java/org/akka/essentials/java/future/example/ProcessOrderActor.java